# Cannot find the right encoding parameters (string to base64)

Tags: c#, string, encoding, utf-8, base64

The following string **amFuZUBkb2UuY29tOkpATjNEb2UxCg==** decodes to **jane@doe.com:J@N3Doe1** (via online decoder).

But when I try to encode the string back ( tobase64) I get a different result. I've tried UT8, ASCII, Unicode. All give different results. I'm using C#.

```
   string str= u + ":" + v;
   byte[] rt = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str.Trim());
   string t= Convert.ToBase64String(rt);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try this :             string input = "amFuZUBkb2UuY29tOkpATjNEb2UxCg==";

            string output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(input));  Should be From not To.

Comment: No, you're not understanding well. I'm trying to find the right way in order to encode jane@doe.com:J@N3Doe1 to amFuZUBkb2UuY29tOkpATjNEb2UxCg==  @jdweng Thanks!

Comment: @TheNoob: Post your answer back!

Comment: Use reverse the process to get the 64 string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your base64 string, this gives us the correct answer of "jane@doe.com:J@N3Doe1\n" (the online encoder didn't clean up your end-of-line):

```
var test = "amFuZUBkb2UuY29tOkpATjNEb2UxCg==";
var output = Convert.FromBase64String(test);
foreach (var b in output){
    Console.Write((char)b);
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

Going back, this gives the string "amFuZUBkb2UuY29tOkpATjNEb2UxCg==":

```
var input = "jane@doe.com:J@N3Doe1\n";
var bytes = input.Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray();

var output = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

If you remove the end-of-line, you get the same string without the "Cg==" at the end.

Comment: That new line char.

Comment: I caught that one by noticing the output from the decoding contained a newline, so I checked the output in the debugger :)